# Jquery draggable show qtip while being dragged

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, qtip2

I want to show tootip on an element when it is being dragged and hide it when the element is dropped/reverted.
I am using qtip2 for the tooltip

My Code:

```
$(".noDrop").qtip({
     content: "You cannot drop this item",
     show: "mousedown",
     position: {
         target: 'mouse',
         viewport: $(window) // Keep it on-screen at all times if possible
     },
     hide: {
         fixed: true, // Helps to prevent the tooltip from hiding ocassionally when tracking!
         event: 'mouseup'
     }
 });
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e6dJq/

I can see the tooltip when the element is clicked, but it is hidden as soon as the dragging starts. Because a clone is created and the element loses focus.
I am not able to keep the tooltip visible until the mouse click is released. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$( ".noDrop" ).on( "dragstart", function( event, ui ) {

  $(".ui-draggable-dragging").qtip(
      content: "You cannot drop this item",
      position: {
          target: 'mouse',
          viewport: $(window) // Keep it on-screen at all times if possible
      },
      hide: {
          fixed: true, // Helps to prevent the tooltip from hiding ocassionally when tracking!
          event: 'mouseup'
      }
  }).qtip("show");
 });
```

It will call qtip on cloned element.

http://jsfiddle.net/e6dJq/2/

[image]

Comment: It is working. But, the tooltips are remaining open unless I hover over them. (Edited your ans with the screenshot for reference)

Comment: I've tested it once again, but such situation didn't happen even once. Maybe it's due to performance or browser? Which browser do you use?

Comment: It happens in some cases when you move your mouse away from the tooltip, without hovering on the tooltip. Updated the screenshot with the mouse pointer path that I moved. btw, Iam using Chrome - v33.*

Comment: I can't find a reason for this problem. Simple (but maybe not the best) solution would be forcing tooltip to close when mouse is unclicked (event mosueup is called). Something like: $(".ui-draggable-dragging").mouseup(function(){ // close tooltip here});

Comment: Yeah, will try using `show:solo` in qtip and `qtip("hide")` in mouseup function. Thank you for the Solution!